Semi Complicated Join Query
I have a few tables that I need to join in a specific way to get the required results.

ACCOUNTS
This is the first table, I need to check every row in here to find the data I need, the relevant fields shown below.  The main columns are ACCTNO and PRI_CUSTOMER_NO, this is the lead customer on the account.



ACCTNO
PRI_CUSTOMER_NO
CUST_CLASS




100186
610234
SME




CUSTOMERROLE
This also uses ACCTNO as above and CUSTOMER_NO, this can the the same as the PRI_CUSTOMER_NO above but there can also be other customers on the same account.  Using ACCTNO can return all customers for that account.



ACCTNO
CUSTOMER_NO




100186
610234


100186
61665


100452
678812




CUSTOMER
This table is as below:



CUSTOMER_NO
LASTNAME
PRIVATE_PHONE
PRIVATE_MOBILE
WORK_PHONE
EMAILSEARCH




610234
Smith
NULL
NULL
NULL
Smith@gmail.com


61665
NULL
846313
NULL
NULL
NULL




CONSUMER
This table as below:



ACCTNO
STATUS_TYPE




100186
30


100199
40




LOCADDRESS


For this table ITEM_ID is the key and it is the CUSTOMER_ID



ITEM_ID
STREET
POSTCODE




61665
High St
SE12RX



For each ACCTNO I need returning, ACCTNO, STATUS_TYPE, CUST_CLASS, LASTNAME, STREET, POSTCODE, PHONE, EMAIL.
I want a result for each ACCTNO so if the PRI_CUSTOMER_NO doesn't have any data for the relevant fields, try looking for data for one of the other customers related to that ACCTNO, if there is no match then return NULL.  If there is some data for one customer but some is missing, you can return data for any customer on that account, so mixing and matching customer numbers is acceptable I just need as many of the fields returning data as possible, as few nulls as possible.
I only need one phone number returning and I don't mind which so if any of PRIVATE_PHONE|PRIVATE_MOBILE|WORK_PHONE has a match just return whichever as PHONE.
So for the above example the output would be as below.



ACCTNO
STATUS_TYPE
CUST_CLASS
LASTNAME
STREET
POSTCODE
PHONE
EMAIL




100186
30
SME
Smith
High St
SE12RX
846313
Smith@gmail.com



Let me know if you need more example data, thanks.

We need example records for your 5 tables and also 1 table with your expected output

How's LOCADDRESS supposed to be joined? Agree with above, you need some example data, but this sounds like a simple join on accno, and then a group by that prioritizes non-empty PRIMARY CUST NO data (using a case when for example)

OK I can get some sample data in soon.

Something like this perhaps:
SELECT  Accounts.ACCTNO
,   consumer.STATUS_TYPE
,   Accounts.CUST_CLASS
,   ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN customer.CUSTOMER_NO = Accounts.PRI_CUSTOMER_NO THEN customer.LASTNAME END), MAX(customer.LASTNAME))
,   ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN customer.CUSTOMER_NO = Accounts.PRI_CUSTOMER_NO THEN LocalAddress.STREET END), MAX(LocalAddress.STREET))
,   ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN customer.CUSTOMER_NO = Accounts.PRI_CUSTOMER_NO THEN LocalAddress.POSTCODE END), MAX(LocalAddress.POSTCODE))
,   ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN customer.CUSTOMER_NO = Accounts.PRI_CUSTOMER_NO THEN COALESCE(customer.PRIVATE_PHONE,customer.PRIVATE_MOBILE,customer.WORK_PHONE) END), MAX(COALESCE(customer.PRIVATE_PHONE,customer.PRIVATE_MOBILE,customer.WORK_PHONE)))
,   ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN customer.CUSTOMER_NO = Accounts.PRI_CUSTOMER_NO THEN EMAILSEARCH END), MAX(customer.EMAILSEARCH))
FROM    (
    VALUES  (100186, 610234, N'SME')
) Accounts (ACCTNO,PRI_CUSTOMER_NO,CUST_CLASS)
INNER JOIN (
    VALUES  (100186, 610234)
    ,   (100186, 61665)
    ,   (100452, 678812)
) customerrole (ACCTNO,CUSTOMER_NO)
    ON  customerrole.ACCTNO = Accounts.ACCTNO
INNER JOIN (
    VALUES  (610234, N'Smith', NULL, NULL, NULL, N'Smith@gmail.com')
    ,   (61665, NULL, 846313, NULL, NULL, NULL)
) customer (CUSTOMER_NO,LASTNAME,PRIVATE_PHONE,PRIVATE_MOBILE,WORK_PHONE,EMAILSEARCH)
    ON  customer.CUSTOMER_NO = customerrole.CUSTOMER_NO
INNER JOIN (
    VALUES  (100186, 30)
    ,   (100199, 40)
) consumer (ACCTNO,STATUS_TYPE)
    ON  consumer.ACCTNO = Accounts.ACCTNO
LEFT JOIN (
    VALUES  (61665, N'High St', N'SE12RX')
) LocalAddress (ITEM_ID,STREET,POSTCODE)
    ON  LocalAddress.ITEM_ID = customer.CUSTOMER_NO
GROUP BY Accounts.ACCTNO
,   consumer.STATUS_TYPE
,   Accounts.CUST_CLASS

I make the join on AcctNo to get all the customers per account, and then by using aggregation, take first and foremost the main customer's data, and then just the MAXIMUM, where non-nulls will come first.

Thanks, I will try this shortly and get back to you, appreciate your time.

Any luck with this one @davidjwest?
